# qemuでホスト-ゲスト間のネットワークが疎通しない

Tags: linux

buildrootで生成したlinuxをqemuで実行したところ、ホスト-ゲスト間のネットワークが疎通しません。
ホスト環境は、ubuntu 16.04 LTS。 qemuは、ubuntuのパッケージをそのまま使用しており

```
    qemu-system-arm -version
    QEMU emulator version 2.5.0 (Debian 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.10), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

です。
qemuの起動は、以下のコマンドで起動しています。

```
    sudo qemu-system-arm -machine vexpress-a9 -smp cores=4 -kernel output/images/zImage \
     -drive file=output/images/rootfs.ext2,if=sd,format=raw -append "root=/dev/mmcblk0 rw console=ttyAMA0" \
     -dtb output/images/vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb -m 512 -serial mon:stdio -nographic \
     -net nic -netdev tap,id=guest0,ifname=tap0
```

起動後、ホストOSの別ターミナルで

```
    $sudo ifconfig tap0 inet 192.168.0.1
```

とし、ゲストOSで

```
    #ifconfig eth0 inet 192.168.0.2
```

としてます。
ここで、ゲストOSから

```
    #ping 192.168.0.1
```

としても、応答が帰ってきません。

気になる点として、qemuの起動時に

> Warning: vlan 0 is not connected to host network
>   Warning: netdev tap0 has no peer

というwarningがでます。

ゲストOSのNICがホストOSのtap0につながっていると考えているのですが、
なにか根本的に勘違いしているのでしょうか？

ホスト-ゲスト間のネットワークを疎通させるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: `sudo ifconfig tap0 inet 192.168.0.1` を実行してから qemu を起動するとどうなりますか？

Comment: やってみましたが、変わらず疎通しませんでした

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己回答です。
qemu-system-arm のオプション`-net nic`を`-net nic,netdev=guest0`とすることで解決しました。